Make frontend maven plugin install node_modules in the same directory as the package.json, NOT in a /node directory
How it works currently:
During the generate-resource phase of the Maven build, the frontend Maven plugin installs all the dependencies in the /node directory created in the working directory specified in the Maven setup.
<configuration>
    <workingDirectory>{path}</workingDirectory>
</configuration>

What I want is to have the plugin install all the dependencies in the same directory the package.json file exists so that, when I manually do npm install, the packages get installed to the same directory 

In frontend-maven-plugin, if you want to configure the installation directory, you should use installDirectory parameter.
So you can use the following.
<configuration>
    <installDirectory>{path}</installDirectory>
</configuration>


Ref: https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#installation-directory
